# Meaning of lock image on DB

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for novice question.

What is the meanning of lock[image] icon on the `*.mdf` file?

Does that mean it is still attached on sql server?

Or it is just due to security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have priviledge lock on the specified folder. If you go on properties for the specified Employee in DB you will find what locks ae assigned and depending on that you can perform actions on the specified Scehduling Employee :) Hope it helps to you.